# Kinect 2 mapping of 2D pixel to 3D Pointcloud2 point

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I see that this is a question that has been answered a couple of times before but all the answers I have found didn't work out. So alas I'll have to ask once more.

In a ROS Nodelet I'm receiving a (approximately) synchronized dataset of 1. a message of type `sensor_msgs::Image` and 2. a message of type `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`, both from a Kinect 2 (using `iai_kinect2` nodelets like `kinect2_bridge`).

What I'm trying to do now is to find a specific point in the PointCloud2 that corresponds to a certain pixel (u, v) in the image. I want to do it for a number of pixels one by one. I broadcast the recognized points via TF2_ROS. That works so far. I can visualize the PointCloud2 and the generated TF frames in RVIZ.

Unfortunately though, it seems that only **some** of the points that I'm searching in the PointCloud2 seem to be located correctly. Although they are correctly located in the 2D image they are not mapped to the correct points in the cloud.

I'm picking the corresponding point from the point cloud like this (kinda pseudo code, don't nail me down to syntax errors):

```
void incoming_callback(sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& pcl, sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& img, int u, int v) {
  int point_index = u * pcl->point_step + v * pcl->row_step;
  int point_idx_x = point_index + pcl->fields[0].offset;
  int point_idx_y = point_index + pcl->fields[1].offset;
  int point_idx_z = point_index + pcl->fields[2].offset;

  float x; 
  float y; 
  float z; 

  memcpy(&x, &pcl->data[point_idx_x], sizeof(float));
  memcpy(&y, &pcl->data[point_idx_y], sizeof(float));
  memcpy(&z, &pcl->data[point_idx_z], sizeof(float));
  .....
}
```

Where u (col) and v (row) are the coordinates of the pixel in the camera image.

I'm not sure why some of the points get mapped wrongly... maybe someone can give me some insight and/or the royal road to do this with `ROS Kinetic Kame`.

Thanks a lot!

### Update 1 - assumption

Alright, I assume that it is related to the spatial offset between the depth image (from the IR camera) and the RGB image. If I could exactly configure the positions of the RGB cam and the IR cam in TF it should work. I just don't know the exact values for the relative positions of the sensors inside the Kinect 2. Anyone?

### Update 2 - manual measurement

Measured it myself and came up with a distance of 50mm (~2") between the sensors. **Still no luck.** So would still appreciate some help! Thanks!

### Update 3 - calibration done

Okay, I've calibrated my Kinect 2. It's a lot better now, at least on the `sd` channel. Some of the points are still off but I think I can solve it by means of some prior knowledge, heuristics, sanity checks etc....

**However**, it's still way off on the `qhd` and the `hd` channel and I don't really understand why. From my algorithm's standpoint it's just a bigger point cloud and a bigger image. It should still match up, no matter what size of cloud and image I feed to the algorithm. I'll investigate further. If anyone around here has a sparking idea, don't hesitate to tell! Thanks!

### Update 4 - output resolution of keypoint extraction

Yay! I've figured it out. The last bit of this problem was the resolution of the reference image of the keypoint extraction algorithm. The coordinates in the output frame did not match the frame used for searching the points in the point cloud. I've made that dynamic and now it works like a charm.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273278/kinect-2-mapping-of-2d-pixel-to-3d-pointcloud2-point/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2017-10-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, so the problem consisted of the following points. Read my updates for details:

- Calibration of the Kinect 2 (yes, it's a tedious process but it has to be done... so rather do it now instead of wasting hours on trying to get around it like me. It's definitely worth it!)
- The frames of the keypoint extraction and the Kinect point cloud have to match, of course. Sounds obvious but it apparently isn't.

---

Originally posted by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) with karma: 1145 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saurabh1987](https://answers.ros.org/users/51673/saurabh1987/) on 2020-10-16**:
Hi
I am trying to solve the same issue. To implement the step in 'Update 4' of your post, I tried to find the part of code that decides "frame and resolution" of the keypoint extraction and those for point cloud. However, I could not find it. Can you please direct me to that part of code?